# how descriptive should a user story be?

Tags: agile-development, use-cases, user-story, agile

I have been tasked to write some user stories to help create a page for transactional history. The standard approach is to follow the now known statement " As a type of user, I want some goal so that some reason" however, the project I am working is quite complex and has a wide range of dependencies.

I am torn between providing a highly descriptive user story and that of providing a more concise version. has anyone faced the same situation before and how was this issue tackled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User stories are usually small, used as a definition of a requirement. Epics are large user stories, typically ones which are too big to implement in a single iteration and therefore they need to be disaggregated into smaller user stories. 
I would recommend to create an epic containing multiple user stories. Each user story should be an end to end "piece" and all together compose the epic "transaction history"

In Agile development (e.g. SCRUM-based projects) user stories should be Independent, Negotiable, Valuable, Estimable, Small and Testable (INVEST). You need to take under consideration the technical effort depending on the team dynamics. So there is need to create/split a user story accordingly.

http://www.alexandercowan.com/best-agile-user-story/

[Write a Great User Story](https://help.rallydev.com/writing-great-user-story)

Comment: Stevy, you know what bothers me with User Stories? There's always this reference to "implement in a single iteration" - here again! I am struggling to keep technical considerations out of my requirements, why should I add project/organizational considerations to them? Maybe a new question?